# Как сделать чтобы gethostbyname возвращала ip в моей сети?

Tags: python, linux

После перехода на debian 12 gethostbyname стала возвращать 127.0.1.1.
Я пробовал удалить строку с этой привязкой в hosts, но не помогло.

Как это исправить? может было у кого нибудь такое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.connect(('1.1.1.1', 1234))
local_ip, local_port = sock.getsockname()
```

`socket.SOCK_DGRAM` - не осуществляет реальное подключение при вызове `connect`.

`('1.1.1.1', 1234)` - любой адрес из сети в которую должен смотреть сокет.

Линукс выбирает подходящий интерфейс и привязывает сокет к нему во время "подключения".

Если не сделать `connect`, то  Линукс отдает первый попавшийся адрес для хоста, а это обычно `127.0.0.1` или `127.0.1.1`.

`gethostbyname` не смотрит локальные адреса, а обращается к ресолверу, который смотрит днс и другие сервисы. Определение локального адреса через gethostbyname никогда не было надежным. Эта функция только для определения внешних адресов.